# Stone Game One Four

Tags: c, programming-challenge

> Alice and Bob are playing a game called "Stone Game". Stone game is a two-player game. Let N be the total number of stones. In each turn, a player can remove either one stone or four stones. The player who picks the last stone, wins. They follow the "Ladies First" norm. Hence Alice is always the one to make the first move. Your task is to find out whether Alice can win, if both play the game optimally.
>
> **Input Format:**
>
> First line starts with T, which is the number of test cases. Each test case will contain N number of stones.
>
> **Output Format: **
>
> Print "Yes" in the case Alice wins, else print "No".
>
> **Constraints:**
>
> ```
> 1<=T<=1000
>
> 1<=N<=10000
> ```
>
> **Sample Input and Output:**
>
> ```
> 3
> 1
> Yes
> 6
> Yes
> 7
> No
> ```

**Here's my code:**

```
#include<stdio.h>

int solve(int N)
    { 
        int x,y;
        int a;                              //checks if alice gets the last stone
        int k;                              //iterate
        x=N/4;
        y=N%4;
        if(y==0)                            //check if N in multiple of 4
          return x%2;                       //if N is odd multiple of 4 alice wins
        else                                //if N is not a multiple of 4
        {
          a=0;                          //initialize
          if(x%2)                       //if N is odd multiple of 4
          {
                for(k=1;k<y;++k)        //loop to check if alice gets the last stone
                    a=++k;
                if(a==y)
                    return 1;
                else
                    return 0;
          }
          else                          //if N is even multiple of 4
          {
                for(k=0;k<y;++k)        //loop to check if alice gets the last stone
                    a=++k;
                if(a==y)
                    return 1;
                else
                    return 0;
          }
       }
    }

    int main()
    {
        int T;                              // Test Cases
        int N;                              // No of stones
        int result;
        int i;                              //iterate
        scanf("%d",&T);
        if(T<1||T>1000)                   //constraints
           return 0;
        for(i=0;i<T;i++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&N);
            if(N<1||N>10000)                //constraints
               return 0;
            result=solve(N);
            if(result)
               printf("Yes\n");
            else
               printf("No\n");
        }
    return 0;
    }
```

The contest engine shows that there are 4 tests with Wrong Answers. I think my code is just fine in every aspect but I can't figure out where my code is failing. I'm a novice in competitive programming and I'd grateful for any help to increase my understanding in the problem.

Comment: So, are you getting the right answer, or not? If you're not getting the right answer, this may be off-topic for this site.

Comment: I'm getting the right results as shown in sample i/p and o/p and a few other which I can think of. I think my code generates the right answers for most of the test cases but the contest engine tells that there are 4 tests with wrong answers and I can't figure out which are those tests.

Comment: In the sample I/O, shouldn't the first line be `3`?

Comment: Sorry, my bad! The first line is 3.

Comment: [This question is being discussed on meta.](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2265/41243)

Comment: What does your code return for 8 stones ?

Comment: what coding challenge site is this from?

Comment: I don't believe this code contains enough content about the error conditions for it to be on-topic on Stack Overflow. Migration would result in a closed question, and a rejected migration.

Comment: `if (N > 1000) printf("Alice and Bob get bored after removing a few hundred stones and stop playing.\n");`

Comment: @Heslacher my code returns 'No' for 8 stones

Comment: @Malachi it is TCS Code-Vita 2014.

Comment: ***Note, this code is part of an ongoing, and current competition, I do not believe getting outside help is in the spirit of that contest. Once the contest is over, maybe***

Answer (score 1):

I see one error. `a` is initialized at the start, and thereafter retains
the value it had in the last test. It should be initialized immediately
before use.

Aside from that, I'm not sure why some of your answers were wrong. With
this structure and without comments, I found it quite difficult to
follow the logic. I recommend the following structural changes:

After `main()` reads each `N`, it should pass it to a `solve(N)`
function that does the work.

`solve(N)` tests various cases. Each case should be preceded by a
comment explaining how the solution is derived for that case.

The cases should not involve more nested blocks than absolutely
necessary. As soon as `solve(N)` finds an answer, it should return the
answer (1 for Yes, 0 for No), and have `main()` do the printing. That
saves print statements, and makes the code shorter in other ways; for
example, this code:

```
if(y==0)
      {
          if(!(x%2==0))
            printf("Yes\n");
          else
            printf("No\n");
      }
```

becomes:

```
if (y == 0)
    return x % 2;
```

Note that `x % 2` is equivalent to `!(x % 2 == 0)`, and is much easier
to read and understand.

Is this code golf or something? It seems excessively brief, at the
expense of clarity. It's better to put spaces around operators and
keywords, and use indentation consistent with the logic. (One of the
many reasons I love Python: it doesn't let you use misleading
indentation. The indentation **is** the logic.)

Your variable declarations should declare one variable per line, with
comments saying what they do (or better, meaningful names that don't
need comments):

```
int T;  // number of tests
int i;  // test iterator
int N;  // number of stones
int k;  // what does it do?
int a;  // what does it do?
int x;  // perhaps rename to Ndiv4
int y;  // perhaps rename to Nmod4
```

The range checks have more parentheses than they need. If they find an
input out of range, they should return 1 instead of 0, since that's an
error.

Statements like `a = ++k;` are legal and have well-defined behavior, but
they're tricky to read and understand. It's better to break them into
two clear statements. It's also better to increment `k` in the `for`
loop introduction if you can (and I don't see why you can't, in these
cases); people are used to reading loops that way, it's an idiom.

Comment: Thanks for the tips about how to write a readable program but my problem is that according to me my code is right but according to the contest engine it produces wrong answers for some cases. Which are those cases? My code doesn't have any syntax or compilation or run time errors. It is just failing a few cases and i want to know which cases they are.

Comment: Does initializing `a` before each use help?

Comment: @invincible, run unit tests, figure out the answers ahead of time and run them through your application to see if it produces the right answer

Comment: ok it neither helps nor does it create a problem.Why do you think it is causing a problem? Run my code in any compiler it will give you the desired result

Comment: Except the compiler at the contest engine, apparently. Well, if you add some comments explaining the logic, others will be more able to find errors.